# Load jquery plugin js after ajax page load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, jquery-plugins

Foe Example, I have page that use `select2` plugin:

```
function Initialize()
{
    if($('.su-tech').length) {
            $('.su-tech').select2({
                allowClear: true,
                width: '100%'
            });
    }
}
```

and html code like this:

```
<select class="select2 su-tech" style="width:100%;">                                                    
    <option value="1" >option1</option>
    <option value="2" >option2</option>
    <option value="3" >option3</option>
</select>
```

also I use ajax to load html content with jQuery:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#page1", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/example-page1",
            success: function (result) {
                $('.ajax_content').html(result);
                Initialize()
            },
        })
    })
```

Now I want to load `js` and `css` each jquery plugin dynamically:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/select2/css/select2.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/vendors/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not insert that jquery plugins references into html?

Comment: select2 is sample, I have many plugin, if I insert jquery plugins references into html my page load speed decrease.

Comment: [Stack answer here...Possibly a duplicate might help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810920/how-do-you-load-a-javascript-file-inside-of-the-success-function-for-ajax)

Comment: Yes $.getScript("myurl/js/bootstrap-popover.js"); is also a way.

Comment: _if I insert jquery plugins references into html my page load speed decrease_ I meant including plugin references into **html response returned by AJAX**. Although CSS cannot be included such way, JS can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Declare a script with id
<script type="text/javascript" id="pluginJS"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pluginJS").attr("src", "pluginJS.js");

    $("#pluginJS").load(function () {
        $("#otherJS").attr("src", "other-plugin.js");
    });
})
```

Call after Ajax Success

```
 $(document).on("click", "#page1", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/example-page1",
            success: function (result) {
                $('.ajax_content').html(result);

                //you can call JS Here
                $("#pluginJS").attr("src", "pluginJS.js");
                $("#pluginJS").load(function () {
                         //After Load PluginJS you can use jQuery
                         Initialize();
                });
            },
        })
})
```

Comment: I have many plugin and want to decrease page load speed. and I want load js per page that has for example select2 plugin

Comment: Yes you can load any of the source as i have mentioned.Apply src to script after page load with condition's you can call which plugin to load for what condition.